# 'Tempdata' does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, tempdata

I am trying to pass some value from one controller to another something like

```
TempData["data"]="data";
```

but it says Tempdata does not exist in current context.So i decided to use ViewBag and surprisingly, i get the same error message for ViewBag.

I read about it and it has something to do with BaseController.So I really have to derive from a basecontroller to make it work?

Comment: More code for context would be helpful.....

Comment: Your controller must be inheriting `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`

Comment: Your controller must be derived from Controller not ControllerBase!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your controller must be derived from `BaseController`
 You can use `TempData[""]` to pass message from one controller to another. Here is a code which will help you:

```
namespace namespaceName.Controllers
{
    public class ControllerName : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult firstController()
        {
            var data = TempData["data"].ToString();
        }
        public ActionResult secondController()
        {
            TempData["data"] = "data";
            return RedirectToAction("firstController");
        }
    }
}
```

the `TempData["data"] = "data"` will be passed to `firstController` from `secondController`
Hope this helps